# Angularjs , display only products what relate with selected category

Tags: angularjs, json, jstree, android-tabs

I'm trying to display all products what under the selecte categoryId.
Sample JSON file :

```
[{
"product_id":"1",
"product_name":"Name of the book 1",
"product_image":"image Url 1",
"category_id":"1"
},
{
"product_id":"2",
"product_name":"Name of the book 2",
"product_image":"image Url 2",
"category_id":"2"
},
{
"product_id":"3",
"product_name":"Name of the book 3",
"product_image":"image Url 3",
"category_id":"3"


}]
```

I have controller like below. I read data from json file. As you see in sample , i can display actual product name in console but i am not able to show in html page.

```
.controller('CategoryDetailCtrl', function($scope, product,$stateParams) {
product.fetch().then(function(data) {
     $scope.dataq=data;
        for (var i=0; i < $scope.dataq.length; i++){
          if ($scope.dataq[i].product_id == $stateParams.categoryId){
               $scope.data=data; 
              console.log($scope.data[i].product_name);
          }  
        } return null;  
})


})
```

Html sample is like below :

```
 <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="p in data" type="item-text-wrap">
    <h2>{{p.product_name}}</h2>      
  </ion-item>
```

Can Anyone help please?

Comment: $scope.data=data;   this part is wrong. I need to assign only value of matched array with i but i don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue by editing controller like

```
.controller('CategoryDetailCtrl', function($scope, product,$stateParams) {
product.fetch().then(function(data) {
     $scope.data=data;  
   $scope.catId=$stateParams.categoryId;


})
```

And used filter function in html side instead of using if in controller

```
ng-repeat="p in data | filter: {category_id: catId}"
```